# Network adapter cannot establish connection

Tags: oracle

I've just installed the jdk and Oracle SQL Developer. I could not create a new connection. It said "Network adapter cannot establish connection". I've look at some websites and videos to fix the problem. I see that they have the listener.ora file but I don't have it. I've check in the services too, there are nothing that is Oracle in there. Can someone please help me, how can I get the listener.ora file? Thank you in advance.

Comment: P.S This is the video link that I have seen.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWdODgQwE6k&t=67s

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate a `listener.ora` file by

> Oracle Net Configuration Assistant

issue these commands to call it :

```
[oracle@yourdb ~] cd $ORACLE_HOME
[oracle@yourdb dbhome_1] netca
```

you'll see a gui tool that tells what you want to do :

> [ Add, Reconfigure, Delete , Rename ]